# Layout messed up after upgrading from Bootstrap 2 to Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just updated my project from TB2 to TB3 and I'm using this [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) for picking date/times.

As you can see on that site, the calendar pops up if you click in the input field of it. This is how it used to work for me as wel before the upgrade. Now it looks like this:

[image]

The calendar is by default popped up, and the date's are still clickable but the input field does not get filled when you're done clicking the date and time. Even the `ValidationMessageError` is by default visible (but for now, forget about that).

This is the mark up I use:

```
<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii">
    <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" id="StartDate" name="StartDate" /> 
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>

<br />

<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii">
    <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" id="EndDate" name="EndDate" /> 
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

This mark up is different from the mark up on the [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). I already replaced the classes with the new ones in TB3. I also updated the bootstrap-datetimepicker.js file which can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/s7T1mn0r).

This is my header mark up:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/chosen.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/datetimepicker.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".chzn-select").chosen();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
```

One of the stackoverflow posts lead me to [this](http://glyphicons.getbootstrap.com/) site for including all bootstrap files (css/js/ghypicons) by adding those links in the header. As you can see, it says above the links 'complete'. I can't see what exactly is included. This [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) needs the `dropdowns.less` and `sprites.less` too for it to work.

If anyone could help me out with my messed up layout, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read that actually the bootstrap-datetimepicker is not compatible with boostrap3.

See: https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/114 , https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/pull/129 and https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/144

You can use a fixed fork (not official) or try another datetimepicker like: http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/